# How to limit number of rows that can be selected in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have got a **DataGridView** with a **MultiSelect=True** in C#.

I want to limit the maximum number of simultaneously selected rows to 2, so that user can select only one or two rows at the same time. How can I achive this?

There are no events like BeforeSelectedRowsChanged or ValidatingSelectedRows.

My DataGridView is Readonly also.

** EDIT **
my SelectionMode is **FullRowSelect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This always leave selected 2 last selected rows

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 2)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Selected = false;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

On the SelectionChanged event you can do this:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 2)
    {
      dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

This will prevent/undo selecting any more cells after selecting two.

For whole rows:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 2)
    {
      dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately. It doesn't allow me to select any rows, after adding above code.

Comment: Depending on your SelectionMode, you might need to use SelectedRows instead of SelectedCells? If you are selecting a whole row with multiple columns, you are right, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding SetSelectedRowCore, calling the base with adding your new limitation to the selected condition.

```
protected virtual void SetSelectedRowCore(int rowIndex,bool selected   )
{
    base(rowIndex, selected && currentSelection < allowedSelectionCount);
}
```

[SetSelectedRowCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.setselectedrowcore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)